# GD SDK send-email API doesn't work with GFE

Tags: ios, good-dynamics

We have an application with Good Dynamics SDK integrated in it, that is supposed to send emails through Good For Enterprise.

We use the following code to call the send-email API :

```
BOOL isRequestAccepted = [GDServiceClient sendTo:@"com.good.gmmiphone" withService:@"com.good.gfeservice.send-email" withVersion:@"1.0.0.0" withMethod:@"sendEmail" withParams:params withAttachments:attachments bringServiceToFront:GDEPreferPeerInForeground requestID:&requestId error:&error];
```

params is a NSDictionary with the value:

```
{
    bcc =     (
        "example@example.com",
        "example@example.com"
    );
    body = "example body";
    cc =     (
        "example@example.com",
        "example@example.com"
    );
    subject = "Diagnostic subject line";
    to =     (
        "example@example.com",
        "example@example.com"
    );
}
```

The method returns TRUE and the error is nil. But the email does not get sent to the specified email ID.

Here are the logs:

```
Apr 15 16:49:19  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Warning>: SCCX509Support::getServerCertificate: certificate \icc_certificate\com.good.gmmiphone.der is not in the cache

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PushConnectionEngine: Connection opened.

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PushConnectionEngine::isPushSocketValid Internal socket for PushConnectionEngine = 0x14e009740 is valid. 

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PolicyComplianceChecker::checkComplianceUnlocked mdmrequired = 0

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PolicyComplianceChecker::checkComplianceUnlocked shouldWipe = 0

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PolicyComplianceChecker::checkComplianceUnlocked shouldBlock = 0

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: GDSecureStorage::setAuthDelegatePolicy, auth delegate policy: com.good.gdgma

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PolicyProcessor::enforceSecurityPolicy auth delegation pair req

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: AUTH  PolicyProcessorAuthDelegate::checkAuthDelegatePairIfNew

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: AUTH  GDSCCManager:sendAuthRequest to com.good.gdgma

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: AUTH  PolicyProcessorAuthDelegate::checkAuthDelegatePairIfNew OUT, m_requestPending: true

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Warning>: PushConnectionEngine: Authentication timeout.

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PushConnectionEngine::isPushSocketValid Internal socket for PushConnectionEngine = 0x14e009740 is valid. 

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PushConnectionEngine: Connection closed.

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: PushConnectionEngine: Reconnecting in 22 seconds.

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: KID   GDDeviceIphone::getSharedGDKID - GDGoodCreatedDeviceIdentifier SA7k59eVj/vUQ4a3C1B5SuTnafdjhikV

Apr 15 16:49:26  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: GTContainerComms:sendCommandV2 - CON_REQ=>com.good.gmmiphone 

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: KID   GDDeviceIphone::getSharedGDKID - GDGoodCreatedDeviceIdentifier SA7k59eVj/vUQ4a3C1B5SuTnafdjhikV

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager:sendRequestAsync: not sending request as app is not active state: 1

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager: Error sending authentication request, will retry with attempt: 1

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: UI    GDLoginViewController:viewDidDisappear: (animated = YES) <GDLoginViewController: 0x14d09c000>

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: KID   GDDeviceIphone::getSharedGDKID - GDGoodCreatedDeviceIdentifier SA7k59eVj/vUQ4a3C1B5SuTnafdjhikV

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager:sendRequestAsync: not sending request as app is not active state: 1

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager: Error sending authentication request, will retry with attempt: 2

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: KID   GDDeviceIphone::getSharedGDKID - GDGoodCreatedDeviceIdentifier SA7k59eVj/vUQ4a3C1B5SuTnafdjhikV

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager:sendRequestAsync: not sending request as app is not active state: 1

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager: Error sending authentication request, will retry with attempt: 3

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Notice>: KID   GDDeviceIphone::getSharedGDKID - GDGoodCreatedDeviceIdentifier SA7k59eVj/vUQ4a3C1B5SuTnafdjhikV

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager:sendRequestAsync: not sending request as app is not active state: 1

Apr 15 16:49:27  iDemo-iPhone[2464] <Error>: GTICCManager: Error sending authentication request, will wait for notification
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If I want to use Good Dynamics for iPhone as client-side, Does server have to support Good Dynamics?